# going back inside navigation controller through embedded view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

In my iOS project I have a main menu that is shown embedded in a container in my initial `UIViewController`. 
After the user choses any row in that menu, the navigation controller pushes the submenu `viewController` that manages further actions, which uses the full window.

If the user wants to go back to main screen, he taps "back" button and my `navigationController` pops back. But when it should pop to the main `viewController` it fails to restore the view of my initial `viewController`.

Do you have any clue how to pop back to the first `viewController` in `navigationViewController` hierarchy if that view controller has containers with embedded view controllers in them?

Or should I consider changing the architecture of my storyboard?

Comment: When you say "it fails to restore the view of my initial `viewController`", do you mean that it fails to restore ANY view, or it fails to restore it with the proper subviews showing?

Comment: you are right, i mean "it fails to restore with the proper subviews showing"

Comment: Your explanation is not very clear. Please explain your VC hierarchy in detail. What is the root view controller for the app? what is the root view controller for the navigation controller? Which VC has the embedded VC? Are you using storyboards and a container view with an embed segue? If you want to pop away view controllers that have child view controllers, the children should be children of VCs that are on the navigation stack, not children of the navigation controller itself.

Comment: @DuncanC The root VC is the UIViewController that has a pair of container views in it. It is embedded in navigationViewController. So i assume than the viewControllers that are embedded (with an embed segue) are also on navigation stack am i right?

Comment: Thorax, no. The child view controllers are children of their parent. If that parent is part of a navigation controller's stack then the children are "along for the ride." You could not pop one of the children from the navigation stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the view controllers in a navigation controller have child view controllers is not important. Only worry about the top-level view controllers that are pushed onto the navigation controller's stack. And only push/pop top-level view controllers, not children.

If you are having problems, you are probably doing something wrong, and will need to post a screenshot of your storyboard, along with the code that shows how you manage your navigation controller stack.

Comment: thank you. That helped to understand a problem and get rid of it

Answer (score 1):

If you want your initial view controller to contain the proper subviews, you either need to hide/show what you need to make it to look like you want in `viewDidDisappear` as the user moves on to a new view, or you need to set it when they come back in `viewWillAppear`.

However your view is set up when you leave is how it will show up when you come back unless you change it. For example, in your root view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    // hide your menu, clean up the view to prepare it for when user pops back
}
```

OR

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // if menu is showing, hide it. Clean up view before user sees it
}
```

Comment: That's a good point. But i don't do that yet as i strive to get my initial view back as it was, before i pushed another VC.